When to use UUID and when to use hash?
I noticed that UUIDs and hash functions can both generate a unique corresponding digest.
And I understand that UUID is a globally unique identifier, mainly used to distinguish devices or certain content.
But I also know that hash functions are mainly used for data authentication and verification.
But I realized that these two seem interchangeable?
After all, they are all used to generate a unique corresponding value.
For example, UUID generates a 128 bit identifier, while MD5 generates a 128 bit digest.
Just like this:
import hashlib
import uuid

uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, 'crypto.stackexchange.com')
# UUID('3a94d39f-c820-58e6-aef7-190fbc5a8862')

hashlib.md5(b'crypto.stackexchange.com').hexdigest()
# f3d81d375363a361dc64c20b4e386b7d

They can both be used to uniquely identify a content, so I have doubts about which one should be used in what situations.


They can both be used to uniquely identify a content, so I have doubts about which one should be used in what situations.

The purpose in common for all UUIDs is that they're intended to be unique. The purpose in common for all cryptographic hashes is that they should have specific security properties, including resistance to finding collisions, first and second preimages (and ideally length extension attacks).
These security properties can facilitate hash functions being used to uniquely identify information, since it should be difficult to find a different piece of information which produces the same hash output. But, they're still prone to the birthday bound, and adversarial brute-force with such things as common input dictionaries and rainbow tables. So, collisions are still possible. And hashing potentially sensitive information doesn't automatically anonymize it, nor is it a form of encryption.
On the other hand, in general UUIDs don't make any specific security claims. They're mainly intended to provide a unique pointer to information, which they're more or less effective at depending on their structure and how they're actually used. A unique pointer doesn't necessarily provide proof of association with that information either. But that can be desirable if the UUIDs are used in ways which shouldn't reveal information about what they're pointing to.
To illustrate, let's look at some forms of unique pointers as Database primary keys, which is the context where UUIDs are often used:




Unique pointer type 1: incrementing counter ID



       Table 1                 Table 2
 -------------------     -------------------
|   ID   |   user       |   ID   |   user
|--------|----------    |--------|----------
|    0   |  "alice"     |    0   |   "jane"
|    1   |    "bob"     |    1   |   "hope"
|    2   |  "alice"     |    2   |  "alice"
 -------------------     -------------------

The primary key is an incrementing counter for each table. So, each row in a table will have a unique ID. But, merging these tables is going to be tricky. Not only are there duplicate IDs — after merging — whatever the intended order of the entries was may not be maintained. To get around this, a global counter could be used:



Unique pointer type 2: global incrementing counter ID



       Table 1                 Table 2
 -------------------     -------------------
|   ID   |   user       |   ID   |   user
|--------|----------    |--------|----------
|    0   |  "alice"     |    2   |   "jane"
|    1   |    "bob"     |    4   |   "hope"
|    3   |  "alice"     |    5   |  "alice"
 -------------------     -------------------

Now these tables can be merged and the counter order is preserved. But, in distributed databases, merging becomes complicated again. If these tables were in two separate remote databases, the global counter would have to be shared and mutably updated. This, modeled as a distributed system, lands in the dreaded synchronization quadrant of concurrent programming.

Figure 1: The Synchronization Quadrant (source)

But there are other global counters which don't need1 coordination or synchronization: Timestamps.



Unique pointer type 3: timestamp ID



         Table 1                 Table 2
   -------------------     -------------------
  |   ID   |   user       |   ID   |   user
  |--------|----------    |--------|----------
0*|  5ae0  |  "alice"     |  5aed  |   "jane"
1*|  5ae0  |    "bob"    †|  5aee  |   "hope"
2†|  5aee  |  "alice"     |  5af3  |  "alice"
   -------------------     -------------------

This gets around the synchronization issue, but we have the duplication problem again. Sometimes remote sites add entries at the same time, or the local clock resolution might not be precise enough to capture the difference between sequential additions.

So, what if local counters are added to the timestamps?



Unique pointer type 4: timestamp + counter ID



         Table 1                 Table 2
   -------------------     -------------------
  |   ID   |   user       |   ID   |   user
  |--------|----------    |--------|----------
0 | 5ae0-0 |  "alice"     | 5aed-0 |   "jane"
1 | 5ae0-1 |    "bob"     | 5aee-1 |   "hope"
2 | 5aee-2 |  "alice"     | 5af3-2 |  "alice"
3†| 5aff-3 |    "eve"    †| 5aff-3 |    "eve"
   -------------------     -------------------

This helps a little. Locally, as long as the counter doesn't wrap back around before the timestamp increments, then the IDs will be unique. But, merging distributed tables can still lead to ID collisions.

This can be dealt with using another unique piece of information: Machine names.



Unique pointer type 5: name + timestamp + counter ID



           Table 1                    Table 2
   ----------------------     ----------------------
  |     ID    |   user       |     ID    |   user
  |-----------|----------    |-----------|----------
0 | ny-5ae0-0 |  "alice"     | ga-5aed-0 |   "jane"
1 | ny-5ae0-1 |    "bob"     | ga-5aee-1 |   "hope"
2 | ny-5aee-2 |  "alice"     | ga-5af3-2 |  "alice"
3*| ny-5aff-3 |    "eve"     | ga-5aff-3 |    "eve"
4 | ny-5aff-0 |    "sky"     | ga-5b08-0 |  "vicky"
5 | ny-5aff-1 |    "mia"     | ga-5b12-1 |    "bob"
6 | ny-5aff-2 |   "nora"     | ga-5b13-2 |    "sky"
7*| ny-5aff-3 |   "liam"     | ga-5bc0-3 |    "zoe"
   ----------------------     ----------------------

This helps in the case of distributed merging, since each machine can have a unique name added to the ID. This is sometimes a MAC address, a location/region, or another identifier (node ID) internal to the system (See: RFC-9562). The above tables, one on the "ny" machine (New York), the other on the "ga" machine (Georgia), can be merged without conflicts if there are no local conflicts. But, local conflicts are possible if the counter overflows. This is shown in Table 1. It uses a two-bit counter, which wrapped around before the timestamp incremented.

Adding a little bit of randomness might help:



Unique pointer type 6: name + timestamp + counter + token ID



             Table 1                         Table 2
   ---------------------------     ---------------------------
  |        ID      |   user       |        ID      |   user
  |----------------|----------    |----------------|----------
0 | ny-5ae0-0-d88b |  "alice"     | ga-5aed-0-c89a |   "jane"
1 | ny-5ae0-1-5df0 |    "bob"     | ga-5aee-1-b5c6 |   "hope"
2 | ny-5aee-2-f741 |  "alice"     | ga-5af3-2-dc34 |  "alice"
3*| ny-5aff-3-1eb9 |    "eve"     | ga-5aff-3-5df0 |    "eve"
4 | ny-5aff-0-64cf |    "sky"     | ga-5b08-0-f9b1 |  "vicky"
5 | ny-5aff-1-10f9 |    "mia"     | ga-5b12-1-6859 |    "bob"
6 | ny-5aff-2-89b0 |   "nora"     | ga-5b13-2-47d3 |    "sky"
7*| ny-5aff-3-1eb9 |   "liam"     | ga-5bc0-3-16e7 |    "zoe"
   ---------------------------     ---------------------------

Unfortunately, random chance didn't help in Table 1. There's an ID collision on lines 3 and 7. But at this point, there's enough potential for unique IDs if some fiddling is done to increase the sizes of the counter, the token, and/or the precision of the timestamp.
But there's still a consideration to be paid to efficiency. These IDs have already become much larger than the lone incrementing counters we started with. By convention, UUIDs are 128-bits. So, to efficiently pack these values into those 16 bytes there's a tradeoff to be made between them. Larger IDs can also be used, and consequently, there's a tradeoff between collision resistance and space. That's why there are several variants of UUID[1-8...]s: each application will need more or less space in the format for specific values based on its expected needs and context.

Another such need is privacy. When these IDs are exposed as something like a URN, it may be undesirable, and even a security risk, to have the internal metadata of the system revealed. Machine names can leak where data is physically located, or allow adversarial routing over the network to back-end resources. Exposed timestamps can enable side-channel attacks without physical access to a system's machines. And auto-incrementing counters reveal the insertion order of database entries.
So, what about hashing the IDs to conceal their contents?



Unique pointer type 7: $H($name + timestamp + counter + token$)$ ID



             Table 1                         Table 2
   ---------------------------     ---------------------------
  |        ID      |   user       |        ID      |   user
  |----------------|----------    |----------------|----------
0 | 917a064971a302 |  "alice"    †| e66efd89a489d3 |   "jane"
1 | 3f5288793eb596 |    "bob"     | 10b7b661a820b6 |   "hope"
2 | 66e6588738899c |  "alice"     | 85f38071f63403 |  "alice"
3*| 4ba1d0a2e8dd29 |    "eve"     | 8691e146fbcda7 |    "eve"
4 | 4ab09f9d1cc1e1 |    "sky"     | 68753a9da9d03e |  "vicky"
5 | 5a609a240ccdab |    "mia"     | 69f3180b02a107 |    "bob"
6†| e66efd89a489d3 |   "nora"     | f2a0e9c27cb45b |    "sky"
7*| 4ba1d0a2e8dd29 |   "liam"     | 7e6e42f1f776f9 |    "zoe"
   ---------------------------     ---------------------------

Well, on top of by chance introducing a new collision between Table 1 and Table 2 on lines 6 and 0, the old collision in Table 1 is still there on lines 3 and 7. Additionally, as was mentioned earlier:

hashing potentially sensitive information doesn't automatically anonymize it, nor is it a form of encryption.

Since the IDs can have a large portion of guessable metadata, brute-forcing their preimages can be feasible. Accordingly, this can't be relied on for hiding its contents unless the random portion of the ID is sufficiently large (based on some security requirement).

Why not just use a random UUID4 then?



Unique pointer type 8: 128-bit UUID4



              Table 1                           Table 2
   -----------------------------     -----------------------------
  |        ID        |    user      |        ID        |    user
  |------------------|----------    |------------------|----------
0 | 917a067971a3029f |  "alice"     | dcc62776c9348e05 |   "jane"
1†| 3f5288793eb596e5 |    "bob"    †| 3f5288793eb596e5 |   "hope"
2 | 66e6587738899ca4 |  "alice"     | 1ec65771bf719bef |  "alice"
3 | 7be5d47bfdb92336 |    "eve"     | 163ef3753a9bbc6a |    "eve"
4 | 8ad9c87c4e1f8a4b |    "sky"     | 9bf2f572456f5886 |  "vicky"
5 | 0c197075e3659915 |    "mia"     | c3bc667b7c8ec91b |    "bob"
6 | e5638273da63d821 |   "nora"     | 29fa9b767e1ba855 |    "sky"
7 | 5fd1e47a3e54662a |   "liam"     | 90071c7ada3f65d8 |    "zoe"
   -----------------------------     -----------------------------

This approach successfully gets rid of the metadata, so they aren't leaked when revealing the IDs. This is good, but collisions are still possible, as is shown on lines 1 in both tables. Now in reality, the chance of collisions on 128-bit random values (and pseudo-random hashes on distinct inputs) is rather small. About $\gtrsim 2^{-42.\overline{66}}$ or $\gtrsim$ 1 in 7 trillion chance for each additional entry after 7 trillion entries. Which is a reasonably small chance for small or short-lived systems. But for large systems, distributed systems, dealing with trillions of resources per day and/or running for many years, this will lead to collisions. Even worse, due to encoding rules, UUID4 only uses 122 random bits. Which leads to $\gtrsim 2^{-40.\overline{66}}$ or $\gtrsim$ 1 in 2 trillion chance for each additional entry after 2 trillion entries.

The collision chances for 128-bit keyed hashes of IDs, to hide their metadata, are similar to situation above, since they can be modeled as pseudo-random functions. They may hide the ID metadata, but they also introduce collisions (eg. reduce the collision-resistance/space ratio).
But, a keyed bijective permutation is different. Similar to why permutations are also recommended to mitigate nonce repeats in counter-based unique-nonce AEAD schemes, bijective permutations always produce unique outputs for each unique input within their specified domain. So, if the permutation, let's call it $\pi$, can be securely keyed, the metadata can also be hidden while remaining unique.



Unique pointer type 9: $\pi($name + timestamp + counter + token$)$ ID



              Table 1                           Table 2
   -----------------------------     -----------------------------
  |        ID        |    user      |        ID        |    user
  |------------------|----------    |------------------|----------
0 | 4a1f8a962973a005 |  "alice"     | a1989849ee6a8108 |   "jane"
1 | eae60b710cfd5fd7 |    "bob"     | 473c552b6225de68 |   "hope"
2 | 5ef18cf6f79d1aa5 |  "alice"     | f7226fb3c15ef83e |  "alice"
3 | bd0bc9f0825cfcc9 |    "eve"     | 767ddd3eba1023ec |    "eve"
4 | 91485e6e3ce43303 |    "sky"     | a13f45a90c5f67ae |  "vicky"
5 | 337198a2bd5b7402 |    "mia"     | c3bc667b7c8ec91b |    "bob"
6 | 68dbe31153740c6a |   "nora"     | 29fa9b767e1ba855 |    "sky"
7 | a86b57f639091051 |   "liam"     | 90071c7ada3f65d8 |    "zoe"
   -----------------------------     -----------------------------

For a 128-bit keyed permutation $\pi$, on unique, 128-bit metadata-containing IDs, unique masked IDs will be produced without collisions. The collision-resistance/space ratio here is optimal, but the computational overhead of creating and inverting the permutation to read the metadata (to sort for instance) is not ideal. Additionally, to maintain the uniqueness property in the distributed setting, the permutation key needs to be shared between all machines creating IDs in the system. In contrast, systems using keyed hashes as masked IDs don't need to share a single key, since their collision probabilities are not noticeably changed under distinct keys on distinct inputs.

1: Timestamps often do use 3rd party synchronization systems like Network Time Protocol.

Brilliant explanation! Thank you for taking the time to educate me and others on this. If I may ask: What would you recommend for a global, distributed system that should be "future-proof" and not locked into one algorithm forever, but able to evolve? Something like Multihash?

TL;DR: UUID's should be thought of as unique identifiers; they do not have any other strong cryptographic properties.
As explicitly stated in the security section of the RFC:

Do not assume that UUIDs are hard to guess; they should not be used
as security capabilities (identifiers whose mere possession grants
access), for example.  A predictable random number source will
exacerbate the situation.


UUID's are there in several forms. They are unique identifiers but they are generally not mathematically bound to the object they are assigned to. They are often used as keys in a database, for example the Windows registry. They are relatively small, using less than 128 bits for their uniqueness. As such they should not be used to protect against adversaries that may alter the input of the hash, as those may try and create a collision.
It's less likely that an adversary can create a collision by having the system create new random objects with their own UUID if the UUID scheme is implemented correctly. Note that time based UUID's are more tricky in that respect, which is why they require a system wide lock.
There is a name-based UUID that does use an MD5 or SHA-1 hash. This is useful if the name is already unique within the name space as it generates a 128 bit unique value. A relatively short, statically sized value is often easier to use as unique identifier than some kind of string combination. The advantage of this scheme is that the UUID may be regenerated from the same name at a later point in time or on a different system.
UUID's may also be used for obfuscation as it is unclear what kind of object is identified by a UUID. If the UUID is name or time based then an adversary may of course try and guess the name or time and generate the same UUID.
Most architects and developers will use a random UUID as they do not rely on a known unique name or a system wide lock in the case of a time based UUID. You do need a well seeded random number generator though. Nowadays most systems do provide such an RNG, but please double check on embedded systems and configure virtual machines to rely on the RNG of the host.

Note that MD5 is not considered a secure hash anymore. For collision resistance cryptographers really require 256 bits minimum (SHA-256 or SHA-3-256 minimum). UUID's are used as easy to use idenfiers to uniquely lookup data and they should not be used for anything else.
For instance, you could use a hash to calculate integrity of data. If you have a hash value from a trusted source then the input message, say a downloaded file from a mirror site, can be tested for integrity and authenticated. UUID's should not be considered for this kind of use case.

Is my following understanding correct? UUID is only used to identify user or device resources, while hashing is typically used for data verification and validation in network security and cryptography, while UUID does not provide any mathematical security.

Yes. Of course you can also use a hash for identification, the fact that a UUID can be constructed from a hash over a canonicalized name clearly shows this principle.

(well, any is a bit mathematical security is maybe a bit much, it is possible to create a relatively random UUID (with just a few bits set to specific values if I remember correctly) and of course a hash over a name can provide some level of integrity of that name, but as indicated, this is not what they are intended for, and using it for anything other than an identifier should be considered a hack).

Some versions of UUID use hash functions to relate the generated UUID to existing "unique" identifiers such as domain names.
If you have only 128-bit storage, then use a version of UUID that employs a good hash function. SHA-1 is an available option IIRC, MD5 should be dis-favored.
If you can afford more storage, SHA-256 is preferred. You can truncate the hash if needed, but don't go below 192-bits - that offers at most 96-bit collision resistance.
